# Inner join and Avg( ) function

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, average

I am using sql-server.I have a table looks like

```
StudentName   Class  score
Jim            a1     80
Ann            a1     83
Bill           a2     90
```

I want to select student whose score is above the average score in his/her class. Here is my code:

```
Select a.StudentName
From Table a
inner Join Table b
On a.score>(select avg(b.score) From b
Where a.class=b.class 
group by class);
```

I think there might be some problem in "where a.class=b.class", Is my inner join method correct here please? Can I also use join?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is sql-server that I am using,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 Select a.StudentName, TableAvg.class, a.score
  From TableA a
  inner Join  (select class, avg(score) as AvgScore
        From TableA 
        group by class)  TableAvg
  On a.score >  TableAvg.AvgScore
  and a.class = TableAvg.class
```

Untested code...

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does TableAvg.class work please? TableAvg is the average score

Comment: please mark as the answer if it you feel it solved your dilemma

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I am finding a way to test it. (I don't have access to Sql-server or oracle now) I have quick question. Usually inner join should follow by another table. Here your answer "TableAvg" is it a table when you select it please?

Comment: TableAvg is the 2nd table in the inner join

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
SELECT 'Jim' AS StudentName, 'A1' AS Class, 80 AS Score
INTO #Temporary
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ann', 'A1', 83
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bill', 'A2', 90
```

Actual query (without needing to join table twice)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT StudentName, Class, Score, AVG(CAST(Score AS FLOAT)) OVER(PARTITION BY Class) AS AvgScore
    FROM #Temporary
) AS T
WHERE T.Score >= T.AvgScore
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Table b(items)` to your `SELECT`
like `b.score , b.class`